# Read CSV with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have the following lines (more, but this sample is fine) in a CSV file.

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2012-11-01,77.60,78.12,77.37,78.05,186200,78.05
2012-10-31,76.96,77.75,76.96,77.47,290700,77.47
2012-10-26,77.30,77.62,76.86,77.36,195100,77.36
```

I need to perform several different functions on the data, each only needing certain fields from a row.  i.e. function 1 will need the 2nd and 3rd sets of data from each line, function 2 will need the 4th set of data.  How would I do that with LINQ (skipping the first line)?

Comment: What have you researched when it comes to parsing a CSV file?  What have you tried so far?  What problems have you had with your attempted solutions?

Comment: I've found the following in other posts while doing research. `let x = l.Split(new [] {',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Select(s => int.Parse(s))`  which seems like a pretty good solution for my problem, but a few things confuse my syntax wise.  The skip command, does that skip a line, or the first segment of a line?  And the split, does that just split the sets of data between commas into separate entities?  that's where I'm confused I guess

Comment: Read the documentation for each method.  That should always be your first step to understanding what those methods do.  You can also experiment by calling each method with hard coded-data and observing the results, to better understand how they work.

Comment: You need a linq tutorial, SO isn't the best place to solicit an entire tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:-

```
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Linq.csv").Select(x => x.Split(','));
            //Considering each line contains same no. of elements
            int lineLength = lines.First().Count();  
            var CSV = lines.Skip(1)
                       .SelectMany(x => x)
                       .Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i % lineLength })
                       .Where(x => x.Index == 2 || x.Index == 3)
                       .Select(x => x.Value);
            foreach (var data in CSV)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
```

Steps:-
**Step 1** - Read all lines from CSV file and split them by Comma(,) which will result in an array os strings with every value.
**Step 2** - Skip the first array (which is holding the headers), then use SelectMany to flatten the list into one, Next you need to set the index for each set(in the flatten list)similar, which I am doing with Select opertaor, the last thing left is filtering & selecting the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow code for   **function 1**

```
var stuff = from l in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
        let x = l.Skip(1).Split(new [] {',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(s => s)
                 .select new
                    {
                      second= s[1],
                      third= s[2]
                    };
```