# save and load contacts as CSV records to a file

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a contact managers program in a console application using a list to store and display the data. I need to view a report that displays a summary of contacts available and then have a menu to allow the user to interact with the program. I have made a method to write contacts as CSV records to a file but I need to make a method to load from CSV records in a file. However I am not sure how to load the record from the CSV records in a file.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
public static void LoadFromFile()
    {

       CODE HERE

    }
     //Save contacts as CSV records to a file
     public static void saveToFile()
    {
        string filePath = "Your path of the location" + "filename.csv";
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath).Close();
        }
        string delimiter = ",";
        string[][] output = new string[][]{
        new string[]{"Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4"} /*add the values that you want inside a csv file. Mostly this function can be used in a foreach loop.*/
        };
        int length = output.GetLength(0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV files are essentially text files with information within the rows separated by commas. You can read them with a `StreamReader`.

For more advance manipulation see here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to parse a CSV file into an object with named properties, as [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/05/24/linq-to-csv-getting-data-the-way-you-want.aspx) or [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789040/read-csv-with-linq) demonstrate.